# php variable scope in functions?

Tags: php, function, scope

How can I access to a variable within a function which defined in another function?

For example:

```
<?php
    function a() {
        $fruit = "apple";

        function b(){
            $country="USA";
            // How can I here access to $fruit
        }

        // And how can I here access to $country  
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can pass `$fruit` as an argument to your `b()`-function. You then return `$country` from your `b()` function and use the response.

Comment: or you can call function inside function:- https://eval.in/1055852

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah, so there is no other way to do that ?

Comment: Sure. There are plenty of creative ways of doing it, but the question is why?

Comment: you can call a method b($fruit), pass the fruit in this method or either you can declare globally that variable for accessing the value.this is not a good you need to make an another function outside that a() function.

Comment: declare it globally so that any functions can access it and use OOP as much as possible

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well actually i'm writing a recursive function(b )  inside another function(a)  , and i need to access to three constant variables  in function b . i just wanted to access to those variables directly without passing it every time.

Comment: @Mehdi, so why ist necessary that thoose constants are definded in this function scope? Just declare those constants globally

Comment: @mr.void suppose a($g,$s) , and $count = count($s)  . so here the variables which do not change are $g , $count . and i have to pass them to another function which is recursive . if i write it  in oop then i won't have any problem .

Comment: If you know how to make it work using OOP, why not do that then? Sounds like you're trying to make it harder for yourself for no (for us known) reason? I also don't see why you would need to declare a function in a function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah i think i'm making it hard ... . and about why i'm declaring a function inside another , i just wanted to use the variables directly otherwise i would declare the second one outside the first  function .  the program i'm trying to write is guitar_subset challenge in sololearn . btw thanks for your help and patience .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use global word.
Try it and tell me if it works.

```
<?php
        function a() {
            $fruit = "apple";

            $country=b();

            // And how can I here access to $country  
        }
            function b(){
    global $fruit;
                $country="USA";
                // How can I here access to $fruit
                return $country;
            }
    ?>
```

,but u should do like that

```
<?php
        function a() {
            $fruit = "apple";

            $country=b($fruit);

            // And how can I here access to $country  
        }
            function b($fruit){
                $country="USA";
                // How can I here access to $fruit
                return $country;
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Using `global` is not good practice. Also `$country` is still not accessible in the function `a`

Comment: why are u defineing functions inside functions :D do like that :D

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is a pretty bad practice, because PHP's functions can't be nested like javascript in this manner. In your example `a` and `b` are both just global functions, and you'll get an error if you try to call `a` twice.

What I suspect you want, is this syntax:

```
function a() {
    $fruit = "apple";
    $country = null;

    $b = function() use ($fruit, &$country) {
        $country="USA";
        // How can I here access to $fruit
    };

    // And how can I here access to $country  
}
```

Of course, you will need to call `$b()` inside `$a()`.